# How do i write a RegEx that starts reading from behind?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a series of words I try to capture.

I have the following problem:

- The string ends with a fixed set of words
- It is not clearly defined how many words the string consists of. However, it should capture all words that start with a upper case letter (German language). Therefore, the left anchor should be the first word starting with lower case.

*Example* (bold is what I try to capture):

- I like **Apple Bananas And Cars**.
- building houses **Might Be Salty + Hard** said Jessica.

This is the *RegEx* I tried so far, it only works, if the "non-capture" string does not include any upper case words:
`/(?:[a-zäöü]*)([\p{L} +().&]+[Cars|Hard])/gu`

Comment: Add sample text in a code block; providing some information about the tools you're using will also help others in answering your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\p{Lu}` for uppercase letters:

```
(?:[\p{Lu}+()&][\p{L}+()&]* )+(?:Cars|Hard)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/rYBaS1eTmBwpXo) (showing matching umlauted letters and ß).

Answer (score 4):

You might start the match with an uppercase character allowing German uppercase chars as well, and then optionally repeat matching either words that start with an uppercase character, or a "special character.

Then end the match with an alternation matching either Hard or Cars.

```
(?<!\S)[A-ZÄÖÜß][a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜẞ]*(?:\s+(?:[A-ZÄÖÜß][a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜẞ]*|[+()&]))*\s+(?:Hard|Cars)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left to prevent starting the match after a non whitespace char
- `[A-ZÄÖÜß][a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜẞ]*` Match a word that starts with an uppercase char
- `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole part

  - `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[A-ZÄÖÜß][a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜẞ]*` Match a word that starts with uppercase
    - `|` Or
    - `[+()&]` Match one of the "special" chars
  - `)` Close the non capture group
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?:Hard|Cars)` Match one of the alternatives
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zXAi3A/1).